# Shared lib '/system/lib/libABC.so' already opened by CL 0x0; can't open in 0x429e5a50

Tags: android

In my android app, I m getting this crash. Could anyone give clue on why this crash is happening?

Log says:

> Shared lib '/system/lib/libABC.so' already opened by CL 0x0; can't open in 0x429e5a50

Does it mean that app is trying to load the .so more than one time in the same app using 
`System.loadLibrary("ABC")`.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

So far, this is the understanding.

As per Java class loader, same .so cannot be loaded in a different classes.
In the log message "**Shared lib '/system/lib/libABC.so' already opened by CL 0x0; can't open in 0x429e5a50**" CL means Class loader.

We can see this part of android code. This is path of android code

**/android/dalvik/vm/Native.cpp**

In this source file, if we observe this part of code from line number 335 to 352, we can see the path of code which leads us to this log message.

```
   pEntry = findSharedLibEntry(pathName)
    if (pEntry != NULL) {
       if (pEntry->classLoader != classLoader) {
            LOGW("Shared lib '%s' already opened by CL %p; can't open in %p",
                pathName, pEntry->classLoader, classLoader);
            return false;
        }
        if (verbose) {
            LOGD("Shared lib '%s' already loaded in same CL %p",
                pathName, classLoader);
        }
        if (!checkOnLoadResult(pEntry))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

So in this code if you see, if two different class in trying to load the same library, then we can see the below part of code getting executed.

```
   if (pEntry->classLoader != classLoader) {
        LOGW("Shared lib '%s' already opened by CL %p; can't open in %p",
            pathName, pEntry->classLoader, classLoader);
        return false;
    }
```

So thats where we have the crash.

Thanks to one of my friends for giving this information.
I appreciate if any edits are made to add valuable info.

Cheers!!